# Fullcalendar format of title of weekview

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

These days i'm working with the fullcalendar.
I want to change the format of the date in the weekview. I found that many people succeeded with columnFormat: { month: 'ddd', week: 'ddd d/M', day: 'dddd d/M' }, but this one doesn't work for me.
Maybe the raison is i used spanish as the language?
Here is my code of calendar and what i want to do. Thank you.

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        //defaultView: 'week',
        locale: "es",
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        //defaultDate: '2016-01-12',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        minTime: "09:30:00",
        maxTime: "19:30:00",
        slotLabelFormat: "h:mm",
        slotDuration: "00:30:00",
        slotLabelInterval: "00:30:00",
        //columnFormat: { month: "ddd", week: "ddd D", day: "dddd" },

        select: function(start, end) {
```

With this code, i got this one now:

[image]

And if i delete the '//' of line of columnFormat, it's like:

[image]

Can someone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [full calendar View-Specific Options](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/View-Specific-Options/)

```
 views: {
  month: {
    columnFormat: 'dddd' // set format for month here
  },
  week: {
    columnFormat: 'ddd d/M' // set format for week here
  },
  day: {
    columnFormat: 'dddd' // set format for day here
  }
},
```

remove `columnFormat` from your code and set `views` config.

Comment: @haozhu Please mark as a answer if it help full to you.

Comment: thank you for the message. i'm also a new user of stackoverflow haha. Now it's done like this? With a green sign right?

Comment: @haozhu Perfect. Green sign for Correct answer and Up and Down for votes :P

Comment: Thank you XD. Will you give you a Up vote when i can vote. And the comment i do now is really to whisper you right? @+other'sname: and type something after?

Answer (score 0):

the correct answer is the day number with a capital D as follow:
if you don't use the capital leeter fullcalendar will not give you the good day number

```
   views: {
        month: {
            editable: false
        },
        week: {
            columnFormat: 'ddd D/M' // set format for week here
        },
    },
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use this:

```
columnFormat: {
    month: "ddd",
    week: "ddd dd",
    day: "dddd"
}
```