# Format date header without the month number FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, date, fullcalendar

In FullCalendar resource timeline, I am trying to change the date display from ddd mm/d to ddd d

The title already tells the user the month, so to make it easier to read for UK folks I want to move away from US date formats.

I tried

```
locale: 'gb',
```

but couldn't get any joy. I have searched but drawing a bit of a blank.

Here's what i have:

[image: FullCalendar image]

and here's what I want:

[image: another FullCalendar image]

It's probably simple!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fullcalendar format of title of weekview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45505064/fullcalendar-format-of-title-of-weekview)

Comment: Have you loaded the relevant locale file into the page, as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/locale ? It's unclear, from your description.

Comment: "gb" isn't a valid language code, "en-gb" (or, by convention, "en-GB") is.

Comment: Look in the console of this demo for all available locale codes: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/LYZXELG?editors=1010

Answer (score 1):

OK, so thanks to @Adyson (again). I had looked at the locales page but failed to notice the JS file that i needed to include.

Thanks to @RobG for reminding me of the correct locale for UK.

Both of these together helped switch MM/DD to DD/MM. Thanks!

Thanks to @Aziz sonawalla - your suggestion didn't get me there because I'm using a newer version.

The key to it was to find (stumble across) the correct item to configure, in this case it was

```
slotLabelFormat
```

So, I used this and it got me just about there:

```
slotLabelFormat:[ { weekday: 'short', day: 'numeric', omitCommas: true },{hour: 'numeric'}],
```

I am using two headers, because i can and it's really nice:

```
slotLabelInterval: [{days: 1},{hours:12}],
```

And this all gets me a top header with 'ddd d' as desired, and a bottom header of '00' or '12'

I would be the happiest person in Donegal if i could change the bottom header to 'AM' and 'PM'. I have tried various changes to the

```
hour: 'numeric'
```

setting but it is beyond my skills to find the right tweak to make. I also tried

```
meridiem: 'A'
```

but that displayed a date only.

Thanks for all the help thus far!

Comment: If you still have an issue with the specific time formatting then it's best to ask a new question about it. A question embedded in an answer won't get much attention